# Meaning of デコ助 in this sentence

Tags: meaning, words, katakana, sports

Context: a boxer is fighting against a defensive opponent that aims to win on points rather than KOs. The trainer of the boxer says:

> 守りも決定打を放つためのもの…　ぶっ倒す欲のねェボクサーなど存在しねェし相手の**デコ助**も例外じゃねェ。　**デコ助**から狙うべきカウンター…ガキはもう見抜いてる。

I thought that デコ could be an abbreviation for `decoy`, but I am not sure. 助 is `help`, but I have no idea how to interpret it together with デコ. Also, I'de be grateful if you could explain if that から means `from` or `after`. My attempt:

> Even defense could be used to blow a decisive punch... A boxer that
>   doesn't want to knock down doesn't exist, and the opponent's __ is not
>   an exception. The boy has already understood that he has to blow a
>   counterpunch from/after the __.

[Here you can see the whole page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDpR5.jpg). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Weblio offers](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%83%87%E3%82%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B1):

> 凸助（でこすけ） 額（おでこ）の出た人をあざけっていう。 また、人をののしっていう時もつかう。 でこぼこやろう

So basically, it's an insult for a person with large forehead(`デコ`). It has an additional collision with 凸凹{でこぼこ} (odd/awkward/clumsy). See also [Goo (Daijisen)](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/151272/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%93%E3%81%99%E3%81%91/)

In general, `-助` can be attached to various words to make a pejorative (or sometimes affectionate) name/handle for someone because it's a pretty common [name suffix](https://jisho.org/search/*%E5%8A%A9%20%23names).

- チビ助{すけ}: Shorty/Little guy
- 寝坊助{ねぼすけ}: sleepyhead
- 飲{の}み助{すけ}: drunkard

Another similar suffix is `-太郎{たろう}`, a stereotypical Japanese name, e.g.:

- ぽん太郎{たろう}: idiot;moron (ぽんつく+太郎)
- 悪{あく}太郎{たろう}: bad boy (to a child)
- ハム太郎{たろう}: Hamtaro (nickname of a hamster, from `ハムスター`(hamster) + `太郎`)

Comment: Thank you very much! I had never heard about -助 or -太郎 as suffixes.